# Get a part of present page url in python using flask

Tags: python, flask

This is my previous page URL : http://localhost:5002/resetpassword.html?token=sushma

preset page url is : http://localhost:5002/login.html

request.url gives me the present page url but how can i get the previous page url using python?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is supposed to be "stateless", so the previous URL is not something stored somewhere by default.

You can however:

- Use the "referer" header, but it's often emptied by the browser
- Store the current URL in a cookie or a session, and get the information on each request (before changing it again), but if the user have the app on multiple tabs, it won't work.

But if it's only for one page, with one login use case, you also can add it on a GET (before redirection) or a POST (in an hidden field) so you can use it later, once the user is logged on.